# How to get a save as dialogue after choosing txt for output

Tags: excel, vba

So, this is my current code which basically just takes values of an excel sheet and puts it into a .txt file.
It just opens/creates a text file in \temp and then saves it there.
I would like to have a save as dialogue pop up after activating the macro where i could save the text file whereever i want. Thanks in advance!

```
Sub ascii_datei_exportieren()


Open "c:\temp\text.txt" For Output As 1

For zeile = 2 To 4
    Text = ""
    For spalte = 2 To 3
        Text = Text & CVar(Cells(zeile, spalte))
        If spalte < 4 Then Text = Text & "|"
        Next
    Print #1, Text
Next

Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: [Application.GetSaveAsFilename method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename)

Comment: Assume you want to be able to browse through your files when selecting, rather than just let the user specify the path?

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, i already looked at that link before posting the question. I just dont know how to put it into my code so it works.

Comment: Enter `[vba] GetSaveAsFilename` in the search box. There will be plenty of examples.

Comment: @dhumphreys Exactly i want to be able to save the file through the explorer with the save as dialogue. I've already gone through pretty much all the other threads but i just cant find a way to apply their solutions to my code.

Comment: I posted an answer. Have a look. You may have to refresh the page to see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Application.GetSaveAsFilename method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename)

> Thanks Siddharth, i already looked at that link before posting the question. I just dont know how to put it into my code so it works. – dani2507 16 mins ago

It is pretty simple actually. Is this what you are trying (**UNTESTED**)?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim fileSaveName As Variant
    Dim zeile As Integer, spalte As Long
    Dim sText As String

    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="sText Files (*.txt), *.txt")

    If fileSaveName <> False Then
        Open fileSaveName For Output As 1

        For zeile = 2 To 4
            sText = ""
            For spalte = 2 To 3
                sText = sText & CVar(Cells(zeile, spalte))
                If spalte < 4 Then sText = sText & "|"
            Next
            Print #1, sText
        Next

        Close #1
    End If
End Sub
```

**TIP**: Avoid using `Text` as a Variable.

Comment: I tried it and it actually works so far, thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, please. It keeps your code like it is and define the folder path prior to `Open ... for Output` sequence:

`Option Explicit`

```
Sub ascii_datei_exportieren()
Dim fileName As String, folderPath As String, zeile As Long
Dim text As String, spalte As Long

 folderPath = GetFolderPath(ThisWorkbook.FullName) ' you can ommit the parameter
 fileName = "text.txt"

 Open folderPath & "\" & fileName For Output As 1
    For zeile = 2 To 4
       text = ""
       For spalte = 2 To 3
           text = text & CVar(Cells(zeile, spalte))
           If spalte < 4 Then text = text & "|"
           Next
       Print #1, text
    Next
 Close #1
End Sub

Private Function GetFolderPath(Optional strPath As String) As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
 Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If strPath <> "" Then .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
 End With
NextCode:
 GetFolderPath = sItem
 Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Generally, it is good to use `Option Explicit` on top of your module and properly dimension all your variable. This will save you for a lot of potential future problems...

Or, you can use the next code to have SaveAs (for text files) dialog:

```
Sub testDialogSaveAsText()
 Dim fileSaveName As String, fileName As String
   fileName = "text.txt"
  fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=fileName, fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

    If fileSaveName <> "" Then
     MsgBox "Saved as " & fileSaveName
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response! I used your code but it lets me select a folder in the explorer but when i try to save it gives me error 76 "Path cannot be found".

Comment: @dani2507: Does it work as you need? Did you test it?

Comment: yes i tested it, however it did not work as i described above. ( I edited my answer to your post, maybe you did not see the full answer in time)

Comment: No problem with me, but using the above solution you can "save the text file wherever I (you) want"... Do you need to select other setting from the dialog, except the path where to be saved?